# Detection of car crash using accelerometer android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an android app which can detect crash of vehicle, by measuring its changing acceleration nd G value, How to calculate G value? Nd How much G value is needed to detect crash? Nd How to detect very big shake event using accelerometer?.

My app is my BSCS final project, please help.

Note: i actually measured G value, nd set 12 G as trigger. But it behave differently on different mobiles. Sometimes takes severe shake events to be triggered or some time just on slightly shaking it reaches to 12 G.

Comment: I'm looking into the same topic nowadays. Were you able to find some good crash detection algorithms?